# Determine the rating for text quality in an Image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, data-science, image-quality

I want to determine the **quality score** of the **text** by giving them some score or rating (something like ' image-text is 90% bad. Texts are not readable ).

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

What I am doing now is I am using the **Blind/referenceless image spatial quality evaluator (BRISQUE)** model to assess the quality.

It gives scores from 0 to 100. 0 score for good quality and 100 for bad quality.

**The problem** I am having with this code is that it is giving bad scores to even good quality "images-texts".
Also, the score exceeds 100 sometimes but according to the [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-image-quality-assessment-in-python-391a6be52c11) I am taking, the score should be between 0 to 100 only.

Can someone please suggest to me how can I get promising and reliable results for assessing the quality of the text-based images?

```py
import collections
from itertools import chain
# import urllib.request as request
import pickle

import numpy as np

import scipy.signal as signal
import scipy.special as special
import scipy.optimize as optimize

# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import skimage.io
import skimage.transform

import cv2

from libsvm import svmutil
from os import listdir

# Calculating Local Mean
def normalize_kernel(kernel):
    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)

def gaussian_kernel2d(n, sigma):
    Y, X = np.indices((n, n)) - int(n/2)
    gaussian_kernel = 1 / (2 * np.pi * sigma ** 2) * np.exp(-(X ** 2 + Y ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    return normalize_kernel(gaussian_kernel)

def local_mean(image, kernel):
    return signal.convolve2d(image, kernel, 'same')

# Calculating the local deviation
def local_deviation(image, local_mean, kernel):
    "Vectorized approximation of local deviation"
    sigma = image ** 2
    sigma = signal.convolve2d(sigma, kernel, 'same')
    return np.sqrt(np.abs(local_mean ** 2 - sigma))


#  Calculate the MSCN coefficients
def calculate_mscn_coefficients(image, kernel_size=6, sigma=7 / 6):
    C = 1 / 255
    kernel = gaussian_kernel2d(kernel_size, sigma=sigma)
    local_mean = signal.convolve2d(image, kernel, 'same')
    local_var = local_deviation(image, local_mean, kernel)

    return (image - local_mean) / (local_var + C)


# It is found that the MSCN coefficients are distributed as a Generalized Gaussian Distribution (GGD) for a broader spectrum of distorted image.
# Calculate GGD
def generalized_gaussian_dist(x, alpha, sigma):
    beta = sigma * np.sqrt(special.gamma(1 / alpha) / special.gamma(3 / alpha))

    coefficient = alpha / (2 * beta() * special.gamma(1 / alpha))
    return coefficient * np.exp(-(np.abs(x) / beta) ** alpha)


# Pairwise products of neighboring MSCN coefficients
def calculate_pair_product_coefficients(mscn_coefficients):
    return collections.OrderedDict({
        'mscn': mscn_coefficients,
        'horizontal': mscn_coefficients[:, :-1] * mscn_coefficients[:, 1:],
        'vertical': mscn_coefficients[:-1, :] * mscn_coefficients[1:, :],
        'main_diagonal': mscn_coefficients[:-1, :-1] * mscn_coefficients[1:, 1:],
        'secondary_diagonal': mscn_coefficients[1:, :-1] * mscn_coefficients[:-1, 1:]
    })


# Asymmetric Generalized Gaussian Distribution (AGGD) model
def asymmetric_generalized_gaussian(x, nu, sigma_l, sigma_r):
    def beta(sigma):
        return sigma * np.sqrt(special.gamma(1 / nu) / special.gamma(3 / nu))

    coefficient = nu / ((beta(sigma_l) + beta(sigma_r)) * special.gamma(1 / nu))
    f = lambda x, sigma: coefficient * np.exp(-(x / beta(sigma)) ** nu)

    return np.where(x < 0, f(-x, sigma_l), f(x, sigma_r))



# Fitting Asymmetric Generalized Gaussian Distribution
def asymmetric_generalized_gaussian_fit(x):
    def estimate_phi(alpha):
        numerator = special.gamma(2 / alpha) ** 2
        denominator = special.gamma(1 / alpha) * special.gamma(3 / alpha)
        return numerator / denominator

    def estimate_r_hat(x):
        size = np.prod(x.shape)
        return (np.sum(np.abs(x)) / size) ** 2 / (np.sum(x ** 2) / size)

    def estimate_R_hat(r_hat, gamma):
        numerator = (gamma ** 3 + 1) * (gamma + 1)
        denominator = (gamma ** 2 + 1) ** 2
        return r_hat * numerator / denominator

    def mean_squares_sum(x, filter=lambda z: z == z):
        filtered_values = x[filter(x)]
        squares_sum = np.sum(filtered_values ** 2)
        return squares_sum / ((filtered_values.shape))

    def estimate_gamma(x):
        left_squares = mean_squares_sum(x, lambda z: z < 0)
        right_squares = mean_squares_sum(x, lambda z: z >= 0)

        return np.sqrt(left_squares) / np.sqrt(right_squares)

    def estimate_alpha(x):
        r_hat = estimate_r_hat(x)
        gamma = estimate_gamma(x)
        R_hat = estimate_R_hat(r_hat, gamma)

        solution = optimize.root(lambda z: estimate_phi(z) - R_hat, [0.2]).x

        return solution[0]

    def estimate_sigma(x, alpha, filter=lambda z: z < 0):
        return np.sqrt(mean_squares_sum(x, filter))

    def estimate_mean(alpha, sigma_l, sigma_r):
        return (sigma_r - sigma_l) * constant * (special.gamma(2 / alpha) / special.gamma(1 / alpha))

    alpha = estimate_alpha(x)
    sigma_l = estimate_sigma(x, alpha, lambda z: z < 0)
    sigma_r = estimate_sigma(x, alpha, lambda z: z >= 0)

    constant = np.sqrt(special.gamma(1 / alpha) / special.gamma(3 / alpha))
    mean = estimate_mean(alpha, sigma_l, sigma_r)

    return alpha, mean, sigma_l, sigma_r


# Calculate BRISQUE features
def calculate_brisque_features(image, kernel_size=7, sigma=7 / 6):
    def calculate_features(coefficients_name, coefficients, accum=np.array([])):
        alpha, mean, sigma_l, sigma_r = asymmetric_generalized_gaussian_fit(coefficients)

        if coefficients_name == 'mscn':
            var = (sigma_l ** 2 + sigma_r ** 2) / 2
            return [alpha, var]

        return [alpha, mean, sigma_l ** 2, sigma_r ** 2]

    mscn_coefficients = calculate_mscn_coefficients(image, kernel_size, sigma)
    coefficients = calculate_pair_product_coefficients(mscn_coefficients)

    features = [calculate_features(name, coeff) for name, coeff in coefficients.items()]
    flatten_features = list(chain.from_iterable(features))
    return np.array(flatten_features, dtype=object)




# Loading image from local machine
def load_image(file):
    return cv2.imread(file)
    # return skimage.io.imread("img.png", plugin='pil')

path = "C:\\Users\\Krishna\\PycharmProjects\\ImageScore\\images2\\"
image_list = listdir(path)

for file in image_list:
    image = load_image(path+file)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # image = load_image()
    # gray_image = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)

    # _ = skimage.io.imshow(image)


    #%%time

    #  Calculate Coefficients
    mscn_coefficients = calculate_mscn_coefficients(gray_image, 7, 7/6)
    coefficients = calculate_pair_product_coefficients(mscn_coefficients)

    # Fit Coefficients to Generalized Gaussian Distributions
    brisque_features = calculate_brisque_features(gray_image, kernel_size=7, sigma=7/6)

    # Resize Image and Calculate BRISQUE Features
    downscaled_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, None, fx=1/2, fy=1/2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    downscale_brisque_features = calculate_brisque_features(downscaled_image, kernel_size=7, sigma=7/6)

    brisque_features = np.concatenate((brisque_features, downscale_brisque_features))


    #  a pretrained SVR model to calculate the quality assessment. However, in order to have good results, we need to scale the features to [-1, 1]
    def scale_features(features):
        with open('normalize.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
            scale_params = pickle.load(handle)

        min_ = np.array(scale_params['min_'])
        max_ = np.array(scale_params['max_'])

        return -1 + (2.0 / (max_ - min_) * (features - min_))


    def calculate_image_quality_score(brisque_features):
        model = svmutil.svm_load_model('brisque_svm.txt')
        scaled_brisque_features = scale_features(brisque_features)

        x, idx = svmutil.gen_svm_nodearray(
            scaled_brisque_features,
            isKernel=(model.param.kernel_type == svmutil.PRECOMPUTED))

        nr_classifier = 1
        prob_estimates = (svmutil.c_double * nr_classifier)()

        return svmutil.libsvm.svm_predict_probability(model, x, prob_estimates)

    print(calculate_image_quality_score(brisque_features))
```

Here is one output for the quality score I am getting for one of the "text-based image"

> 156.04440687506016

Comment: The answer is Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Bilal Thank you very much for the tour. It was very helpful. I have now edited my question to be more specific and clear. Hope this helps now. Please let me know if more information is needed.  I really need the solution and want to be as much clear with my question as possible.